# Allegro Embedded ElasticSearch Fails Error: Cluster does not reached yellow status in specified timeout

Tags: elasticsearch

Im running integration tests with elasticsearch using allegro embedded elasticserach https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch.

The trace for this error is

```
Cluster does not reached yellow status in specified timeout
Response body:
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"red","timed_out":true,"number_of_nodes":2,"number_of_data_nodes":2,"active_primary_shards":0,"active_shards":0,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":10,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":2,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":3,"active_shards_percent_as_number":0.0}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cluster does not reached yellow status in specified timeout
Response body:
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"red","timed_out":true,"number_of_nodes":2,"number_of_data_nodes":2,"active_primary_shards":0,"active_shards":0,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":10,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":2,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":3,"active_shards_percent_as_number":0.0}
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticRestClient.assertOk(ElasticRestClient.java:197)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticRestClient.lambda$waitForClusterYellow$6(ElasticRestClient.java:121)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.HttpClient.lambda$execute$1(HttpClient.java:24)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.HttpClient.execute(HttpClient.java:31)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.HttpClient.execute(HttpClient.java:23)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticRestClient.waitForClusterYellow(ElasticRestClient.java:121)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticRestClient.createIndices(ElasticRestClient.java:52)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.EmbeddedElastic.createIndices(EmbeddedElastic.java:194)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.EmbeddedElastic.start(EmbeddedElastic.java:66)
    at com.spireon.kahuavs.ingest.integration.test.BaseTest.setupEmbeddedES(BaseTest.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

None of the other developers on my team are running into this error when running the tests on their computer. The waitForClusterYellow function has its timeout set to 60 seconds, and I don't think that function is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Using activity monitor on my Mac and killing all the java processes resolved my issue.